# Whats the best option for generating links using helpers with ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

What's the best option for generating links using helpers in ASP.NET MVC 3?

As far as I can see it's better to use `Url.RouteUrl` and `Html.RouteLink` helpers than `Url.Action` and `Html.ActionLink` to generate links because the first two allow you to use `RouteName` instead of `Controller` and `Action` for url pattern matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does *best* mean in this context?

Does it mean:

- Easy for Front End developers to code against? (e.g., do they have to write C# to make a link?)
- Easy to maintain if you change where the links point to a lot?
- Easy for new developers to follow?
- Best if you use strongly typed objects to make your links?
- Best if you have very little information that you need for each link?

Because there are so many ways to make links, and each method has a different purpose, I use all of them at different times, but I normally just wrap the link in a `HtmlHelper` method and create a strong name for it:

```
public static MvcHtmlString GenerateProductUrl(this Urlhelper helper, Product product)
{
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(
        helper.RouteUrl(
            "widgetlink", 
            new {
                    productID = product.ProductId, 
                    productName = product.ProductName.ToUrlSlug() 
                }
        )
    );
}
```

Then you call call this as follows:

```
<a href="<%= Url.GenerateProductUrl(Model.Product) %>" class="xurl"><%= Html.Encode(Model.Product.Name) %></a>
```

If you prefer to have a whole link generated for you (probably because you don't have specialized CSS classes for individual links), then you could use this:

```
public static MvcHtmlString GenerateProductLink(this Htmlhelper helper, Product product)
{
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(
        helper.RouteLink(
            "widgetlink", 
            new {
                    productID = product.ProductId, 
                    productName = product.ProductName.ToUrlSlug() 
                }
        )
    );
}
```

Using HtmlHelpers and UrlHelpers gives you the following advantages:

- One canonical place to change links
- Easy name to remember, with Intellisense generation (Start typing `Html.` and all of your links show up, especially if you put `Generate` as the prefix to generate links and URLs
- Use HtmlHelpers when you need a whole link encapsulated, and use `UrlHelpers` when you just need something to build a URL

I go into this at length in a blog post I wrote where I listed some [tips for writing URLs in ASP.NET MVC](http://blog.yapb.net/yapb/blog/post/2011/08/08/URL-writing-tips-for-ASPNET-MVC.aspx).

Comment: I was talking more about maintenance. For me its easy to do it by RouteName cause this way im pointing directly to one route. But i think that your solution of Wrap the helper looks even better. Thanks for the clear & good response.

Answer (score 0):

you tried to use    @html.ActionLink();?

Comment: Yes, i tried, in my opinion its better to use Html.RouteLink cause i prefer to choose by routename than by Controller/Action pair. Are you agree on this? Greetings.

Comment: i prefer to use controller/Action. you should use the routelink if you like it more and it does the job for you.